# .replace() not working for umlaut characters on safari using snow leopard

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters

i have a function that removes special characters from any given value, but my replace for german umlaut characters doesn't seem to work on safari in snow leopard:

```
this_string = this_string.replace(/Ä/g, '&#196;');
```

i assume, it doesn't find the umlaut in a text. i wasn't too sure about this, so i checked for the case that my replacement wouldn't be accepted and replaced the umlaut with a word:

```
this_string = this_string.replace(/Ä/g, 'test');
```

but i still ended up with the original content. browsing google for a solution only ended up in finding posts that gave my code as the correct way to replace the characters.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all future readers of this question:

The problem was that I had to set the encoding of my .js file to an umlaut compatible format.

Have fun coding! =)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
this_string = this_string.replace("Ä", 'test');
```